# ionic side menue not displaying

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to ad a new view/page with a header and sidemenu to an existing project. However I seem to get the syntax wrong.

ion-side-menus:

```
     <ion-side-menus >

<!-- Center content -->
<ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
  <ion-header-bar style=" background-color:#3A5B89">
      <button menu-toggle="left"  class="button button-clear button-light "> menu</button>
    <h1 class="title" style=" text-align:left; color:white;">Medexter Demo KIS</h1>
      <div class="BTNright">
      <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Print</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Back</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Redo</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Search</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Help</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Log Out</button>
      </div>
  </ion-header-bar>

</ion-side-menu-content>


<!-- Left menu -->
<ion-side-menu side="left" expose-aside-when="large" width="150" >
  <ion-header-bar >
    <h1 class="title">Projects</h1>
  </ion-header-bar >
    <ion-content >
       <ion-list >
    <ion-item >
      Dashoboard
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Patients
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Laboratory
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Ambulance
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Forms
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Medication
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Reporting
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Preferences
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

"page" content:

```
<ion-content scroll="false"  class="has-header">

        <ion-list style="float:left; overflow-y:scroll; height:100vh">
          <ion-item ng-repeat=" patient in patientList" style="font-size:80%;" >
            {{patient.Lname}}, {{patient.Fname}}
          </ion-item>
          </ion-list>



          <h1>Search</h1>

        <ion-list>
    <ion-item >
      Search
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Browse
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item >
      Playlists
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

When I wrap both the menu part and the main view in the  tag it does display the header and the main view, however when toggling the side menu it is behind my main view which does not slide to the right. In addition the `<h1>Search</h1>` just vanishes.

```
        <!-- Center content -->
    <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
      <ion-header-bar style=" background-color:#3A5B89">
          <button menu-toggle="left"  class="button button-clear button-light "> menu</button>
        <h1 class="title" style=" text-align:left; color:white;">Medexter Demo KIS</h1>
          <div class="BTNright">
          <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Print</button>
          <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Back</button>
          <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Redo</button>
          <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Search</button>
          <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Help</button>
          <button class="button button-clear button-light smallFont">Log Out</button>
          </div>
      </ion-header-bar>
< ion-content>
 MAIN VIEW CODE
 </ion-content>

    </ion-side-menu-content>
```

When I put it inside the `<ion-side-menu-content>` tag of the header everything works. HOwever, all tutotials and demos I found on this topic have both codes seperate. 
Which approach is the right one? can I keep the main view inside the Header tag?

Comment: may be it is because of your **ion-side-menu-content** is first i think **<ion-side-menu side="left">** should be first then only  your side-menu-content comes it is the basic structure for side-menus given in http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/

Comment: My solution was to start from scratch and insert parts from my already existing project. I still don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: can you provide me plunkr or jsfiddel